# Is it possible to tell Pandas to NOT escape single quotes in JSON data

Tags: python, json, pandas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to use `df.itertuples` to loop over each row and insert in to Snowflake. I was originally trying to use `df.to_sql()`, but this wasn't creating the table properly so my `VARIANT` type columns were instead being turned in to `VARCHAR`. I want to keep it as `VARIANT` so that I can properly use the json features of Snowflake.

Now the new issue is with my loop. `Pandas` is automatically escaping single quotes within the json since it wraps the entire value in single quotes already. Any of my json data that has single quotes in the values themselves now throws an error on insert when using Snowflakes `PARSE_JSON` function which will return a `VARIANT` type on successful parse.

My code looks like this currently. So is there a way to make it so `Pandas` DOES NOT escape these single quotes in a string that stores JSON?

```
for row in prod_df.itertuples(index=False):
    try:
        cursor.execute(
            f"""INSERT INTO NORSE_PROD.{snowflake_resource.schema_}.{table_name} SELECT
                '{row.ID}',
                '{row.TENANT_ID}',
                '{row.SERVICE_AT_LOCATION_ID}',
                '{row.SERVICE_ID}',
                '{row.LOCATION_ID}',
                '{row.ORGANIZATION_ID}',
                PARSE_JSON('{row.CONTACT}'),
                PARSE_JSON('{row.SOURCE_SERVICE_AREA}'),
                PARSE_JSON('{row.LOCATION}'),
                PARSE_JSON('{row.PHYSICAL_ADDRESS}')
            """
        )
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print(row)
```

Comment: Don't use string formatting to create a SQL query. Use placeholders in the SQL and values in the second argument to `cursor.execute()`. See the linked question.